# How to permanently save heavy data in the client-side in a Vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vuex, clientside-caching

I have a heavy data in my vuex store that I need to keep even after a refresh for performance purposes.
Are there any proposals except LocalStorage ?

Comment: Depends how *heavy* the data is. WebSQL storage is deprecated but can hold about 20-50MB. After that the user is notified if using more storage space is allowed. [WebSQL Tutorial](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/tutorial-web-sql-database-138)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing "heavy data" is possible **up to 1GB** within browsers.
Possible through https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Maybe this article is interesting for you. It implements a vuex solution with indexedDB https://netterminalmachine.com/blog/2018/persisting-a-vuex-store-to-indexed-db

I figured this max space limit of 1GB out the hard way myself. Browsers like Chrome or Firefox will ask you to increase space limit when you need more than 1GB.
**Safari does not**. Its hard capped at ~1024MB storage.
If you need more than that you need a native app solution. (Hint: "Chrome" on MacOS devices like iPad, iPhone use Safari under the hood)